# Convert a CSS hover menu to jQuery Menu

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I found a blog post on [creating the menu found in gmail with css dropdown](http://blog.geotitles.com/2011/10/creating-top-fixed-menu-bar-with-css3-buttons-found-in-gmail/).

The dropdown is displayed when we hover over the buttons but I want to convert this to a jQuery menu

where the dropdown is displayed when we click on a button rather than on mouseover, Please help.

Thanks in advance .

http://jsfiddle.net/PSUkW/

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are happy to help if you encounter specific problems as you write your code, but we will not (in most cases) write it for you.

Comment: I want to know how to convert ?
so probably an example code could help since I am not that good at jQuery

Comment: http://www.jquery.com is full of helpful examples.

Comment: Thanks sir, if you can't help then please don't.

Comment: They are helping. I was bored enough to write the four lines of code, but that should be your job. If you don't understand jQuery, then learn it. It isn't that hard.

Comment: I have started to learn, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple logic. I replaced a few of the `:hover` CSS rules with a `.clicked` class and added this JS:

```
$('.menu > ul > li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

Instead of allowing the browser to trigger the dropdown with the `:hover` pseudo class, I have jQuery toggle the class `.clicked` on each top-level `li` clicked. This produces the same behavior, but with JS.

This line:

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('clicked');
```

Basically removes the `clicked` class from the siblings of that element, which allows the user to drop down only one menu at a time (otherwise overlap occurs).

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PSUkW/5/**

Comment: You deleted your comment, but here's the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/PSUkW/16/.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help.(deleted the comment on your advice that it is my job to get it done)

Comment: No problem. jQuery isn't hard to learn. Once you do, it's easy to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simply. Inside of the CSS adding styles and showing the dropdown on li:hover, you can update it to add a class: something like `.menu ul li.click ul`. And then 2 lines of jQuery to target that click action.

See the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/PSUkW/3/

Comment: @Shobha V - See this link: http://jsfiddle.net/PSUkW/9/ I updated the code to remove all instances of the `click` class, then on the specific LI that was clicked, add the `click` class to enable the dropdown if it has one.